# Selecting random letters for Hangman

Tags: python

```
flink = open("C:/python27/2of12inf.txt", "rU") 
words = [ ]            
for eachline in flink :      
    words += [eachline.strip()]
flink.close()                
print "%d words read" % len(words)
return words
```

how do I select 6 random letters from this list?

Comment: Random letters, or a random word?

Comment: I wouldn't use the Python installation directory as working space if I were you.

Comment: select the first letter every time :)

Comment: You can replace your three lines that read in the file with `words = [eachline.strip() for eachline in flink]`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I can think of is to randomize the entire list and take as many elements as you need:

```
>>> words = "one two three four five six seven eight nine ten".split()
>>> import random
>>> random.shuffle(words)
>>> words[:6]
['two', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'four', 'one']
>>> random.shuffle(words)
>>> words[:6]
['five', 'seven', 'nine', 'three', 'four', 'eight']
```

Answer (score 0):

random.sample is a little cleaner

```
>>>words = "one two three four five six seven eight nine ten".split()

>>>import random

>>>random.sample(words, 6)
['six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'three', 'ten']

>>>random.sample(words, 6)
['three', 'five', 'four', 'six', 'one', 'ten']

>>>random.sample(words, 6)
['ten', 'five', 'two', 'nine', 'seven', 'eight']
```

Answer (score 0):

This function returns a random string from the passed list of strings.

```
 def getRandomWord(wordList):
     wordIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordList) - 1)
     return wordList[wordIndex]
```

this function gets a random word using the def above.

```
 secretword = Randomword(hangmanwords)
```